# Protractor retrieve single element from ElementArrayFinder

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I want to retrieve the first element from a ElementArrayFinder matching a condition. The following code provides me with the element that I'm expecting but it goes through all elements which takes time.

Is there any way to this?

```
    return content.all(by.css('.class')).filter(function(label){
        return label.getText().then(function(text){
            return text === searchName;
        }); 
    }).first();
```

CONCLUSION:
Answer provided by [Sudharsan Selvaraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6405587/sudharsan-selvaraj) worked as a charm

```
var ele = content.all(by.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'class')][normalize-space(text())='some-value']")).first()
```

Reduced drastically time searching the element

The answer provided by [Florent B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887618/florent-b) also solves the problem and looks like a much simpler approach.

`return content.element(by.cssContainingText('.class', searchName));`

Comment: You could try a more specific locator so it's not pulling as many results.

Comment: It's a table with results, don't think I can be more specific here. Would like some behaviour similar to Array.prototype.some but can't figure how to apply it in a protractor context. @Gunderson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the locator `by.cssContainingText` to find an element by CSS and text:

```js
return content.element(by.cssContainingText('.class', searchName));
```

Comment: It works great. Though it behaves the same way as using xpath, it feels like a more intuitive approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to find the element with specific text.Look at below sample xpath.

```
var ele = content.all(by.xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'class')][normalize-space(text())='some-value']")).first()
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you directly access the first element of the label?

```
return content.all(by.css('.class label')).first().getText().then(function (text) {
      return text === searchName;
 });
```

P.S. I didn't test the code but it should probably work

Comment: I might not explained it clearly.  But the that code doesn't even provide the same return ElementFinder if I'm not mistaken.  
If I just wanted the first element I could just do:  
`return content.all(by.css('.class')).first();`
But I want it to match a condition  
Pseudo example: `['a', 'b', .... , 'zzzz'] -> ['b']`
I only want the 'b' element but I don't want to go through all the elements after finding it.  
@rampasala hope this is a more clear explanation and thanks for the answer :)